# scroll up or down and pull to refresh for Onsen UI and angularjs hybrid app

Tags: angularjs, scroll, onsen-ui, pull-to-refresh

I created a hybrid app with Onsen UI and angularjs, and i want to let the page scroll up or down and pull to refresh. I added the iScroll but it doesn't work, I don't know whether it does not work. Is it conflicted between Onsen UI and angularjs? How to fix it? Many thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding a little bit, but isn't [this](https://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/vKxyvO?editors=1010) what you want?

If you use Onsen UI you can still scroll the page normally. To get the pull to refresh functionality you just need an `ons-pull-hook` tag inside the page. So something like this

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-pull-hook>Pull to refresh</ons-pull-hook>

  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
</ons-page>
```

should work just fine.

> I added the iScroll but it doesn't work, I don't know whether it does not work.

iScroll is not necessary for this scenario. You can add it later if you want, but maybe lets try to make everything work without it first. If the problem occurs only after you add iScroll then I can update my answer later.

> Is it conflicted between Onsen UI and angularjs?

There shouldn't be any conflict between the two. A big question here is whether you're using Onsen 1 or Onsen 2. Onsen 1 was actually based on Angular, while Onsen 2 doesn't require Angular to work.

> How to fix it?

Currently I'm not sure where the problem lies exactly.

If you're worried about the initialisation of either Angular, Onsen or iScroll then maybe sharing your initialisation code would be useful for a better answer.